# Will adb restore increment the custom binary flash counter?

Tags: adb, backup, samsung

With `adb backup` an archive of all apps and their data can be retrieved from the phone. I could not find any clear information which exact files and partitions are accessed during the process. If it modifies `/system`, could this affect custom flash counter found on most Samsung devices, when `adb restore` is applied?

Comment: Why should it do that? `adb restore` is not flashing anything, it's simply unpacking files from the specified backup archive.

Comment: I do not know what exactly are the contents of the backup and what parts of the android system are affected. I hope my edit clarifies this.